# Can't deploy webpack to gh-pages (react app)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, github-pages

First time using webpack as well as deploying using gh-pages. I cloned a webpack project from a udemy course. Instructor doesn't get into how to actually use webpack. It's telling me that [etc.]/build doesn't exist. When I create a build folder, I get the same error.

package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "build": "webpack -p --config ./webpack.production.config.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
```

webpack.production.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: "/WeatherReact/",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel",
        query: {
          presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-1"]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: "./",
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
  }
};
```

When I run yarn run deploy:

```
> webpack -p --config ./webpack.production.config.js

Hash: 252097b8991e3c14f1e3
Version: webpack 1.15.0
Time: 8098ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  456 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
    + 111 hidden modules

WARNING in bundle.js from UglifyJs
Side effects in initialization of unused variable subscriptionShape [./~/react-redux/lib/utils/PropTypes.js:12,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable storeShape [./~/react-redux/lib/utils/PropTypes.js:19,0]
Condition always true [./~/hoist-non-react-statics/index.js:6,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable support [./~/lodash/index.js:932,0]
Condition always true [./~/lodash/index.js:12323,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/lodash/index.js:12337,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable moduleExports [./~/lodash/index.js:266,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:2297,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:5500,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14809,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15147,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15212,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15331,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15338,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15346,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15351,5]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11616,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11680,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11723,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11758,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11775,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11811,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11825,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11883,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11290,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16191,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16200,0]
Declarations in unreachable code! [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16200,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16201,0]
Dropping unused variable parentNamespace [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16200,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16383,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16397,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16416,0]
Condition left of && always true [./~/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16421,0]
Condition always true [./~/react-sparklines/build/index.js:2,0]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/react-sparklines/build/index.js:4,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable width [./~/react-sparklines/build/index.js:1511,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable width [./~/react-sparklines/build/index.js:1626,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable width [./~/react-sparklines/build/index.js:1843,0]
Side effects in initialization of unused variable height [./~/react-sparklines/build/index.js:1844,0]
Condition always true [./~/symbol-observable/lib/index.js:22,1]
Dropping unreachable code [./~/symbol-observable/lib/index.js:25,0]
$ gh-pages -d build
ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/zacharysedefian/Projects/React/WeatherReact/build'
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: maybe `create-react-app` would be a better choice for you?

Comment: It would. But the project I forked was made with webpack. And when I tried to migrate over the components to a create-react-app, I actually had even more errors (google maps integration, styles were missing, CORS block, etc.)

Comment: @BlakeSedefian, I have had this problem as well and I did not get a good answer either from SO nor from Github customer support in the past. Or at least not an answer that made sense to me. Have you looked into alternatives to gh-pages? Do you have that flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error because `build/` does not exist. Using the `-d` (or `--dir`) flag sets the `basePath` for the *gh-pages* tool.

You can change the script within `package.json` to `"deploy": "gh-pages -d WeatherReact"` which should deploy that folder and its contents.

[CLI rules on gh-pages Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLFda.png) 
https://github.com/afc163/gh-pages-cli