# How do I configure Webpack for production in my React app? (Github pages)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, github-pages, dev-to-production, webpack-production

My React app throws `404 errors` in production when accessing static files (stylesheets, utilities, and more). The development environment works fine. After debugging for several days and further research I believe it's a webpack pathing issue as my understanding of build path and `webpack.output` is still lacking despite my research on [webpack.js.org](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#root). After referencing other posts, I still can't grasp this final concept for bundling applications. All help is appreciated. See below for **Things tried**, and **Posts referenced**, and **Notes** for my process. Thank you.

**Things tried**:

1. Added "homepage" property in package.json pointing to "https://my_ghub_username.github.io/project_repo/"
2. Changed `"homepage"` property to `"."`
3. Changing React router to `<HashRouter/>` ensuring it imported correctly.
4. Pushed my latest changes to main before deploying my app to GH pages again
5. Added `package.json` scripts to `pre-deploy`, `deploy`, && `build`

**Posts/Guides Referenced**

1. [How to deploy a React app to GitHub Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59972396/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-to-github-pages)
2. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages-https-pagesgithubcom
3. [Can't deploy webpack to gh-pages (react app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284888/cant-deploy-webpack-to-gh-pages-react-app)

I attached snippets of relevant code `package.json`(*I*), `webpack.dev/prod/common.js`(*II*), `index.html`(*III*), file tree(*IV*), and errors(*V*) in chrome tools.

(*I*)

```js
{
  "name": "digital-nomad",
  "version": "1.2.2",
  "description": "An immersive experience to experience life in major cities!",
  "main": "index.jsx",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d dist",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.dev.js"
  },
  "homepage": ".",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "googleapis": "^64.0.0",
    "inline-source-map": "^0.6.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.2",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

(*IIA*)

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const common = require('./webpack.common.js')



module.exports = merge(common, {

  mode: 'development',

  devtool: 'inline-source-map',

  devServer: {
    contentBase: './',
    compress: true,
    open: true,
    port: 8080,
    watchContentBase: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }

})
```

(*IIB*)

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge')
const common = require('./webpack.common.js')


module.exports = merge(common, {

  mode: "production",

  devtool: "source-map",

})
```

(*IIC*)

```js
const path = require('path')

const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
  title: 'Production',
  template: __dirname + '/index.html',
  filename: 'index.html',
  inject: 'body',
  favicon: "favicon.png"
})


module.exports = {

  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.jsx" ),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: './'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /(node_modules)/, 
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react'] }
        },
      }, 
      { test: /\.css$/i, 
        use: [ 
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: { publicPath: '../' }
          }, 
          'css-loader'
        ],
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [ 
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    HTMLWebpackPluginConfig 
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".css", "*"]
  },

  performance: {
    hints: false
  },

  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,
    warnings: true,
    colors: true,
  },


};
```

(*III*)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">

    <!-- youtube video API -->
  <script rel='preload' src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <!-- youtube data API -->
  <script rel='preload' src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>

  <script defer src="./src/utils/YTVideoAPI.js"></script>
  <script defer src="./src/utils/YTDataAPI.js"></script>

  <script src="/dist/bundle.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/stylesheets/player.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/stylesheets/root.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./src/stylesheets/controls.css">

  <title>Digital Nomad</title>
</head>
<body>.
  
  <div id="root"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

(*IV*)

[FileTree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESLy5.png)

(*V*)

```js
GET https://username.github.io/project_name/src/stylesheets/player.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

**Note**

I tried my hand over the past couple of days with alternative solutions like utilizing a 404 page to redirect to my app while still using `Browser router` as a potential solution but not understanding this last aspect of webpack is killing me since I know I can use webpack to my advantage. ( I really want to better conceptualize webpack pathing to improve existing apps ).

Lastly, any feedback on code quality, convention, and implementation is extremely welcome.